# Allowing full file path in URI for Web API call

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-web-api2

I am currently working on a 'download file' implementation using Web API 2.

However, as the files that can be downloaded are NOT stored in the database, I am passing in the full file path as the parameter for identification.

It seems the problem with this approach is that the filePath contains characters that are invalid for a URI... Has anyone got any suggestions to resolve this or an alternate approach?

**Download file method:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Files/{*filePath}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri]string filePath)
    {
        try
        {
            var file = new FileInfo(filePath);

            byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

            var result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

            result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = file.Name + file.Extension;

            return result;

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requiring the client to put the full path in the URI (even if it were encoded so that it only contains valid characters for the URI) implies that you may be publishing these paths somewhere... this is not a great idea for a few reasons:

1. Security - [full Path Disclosure](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Full_Path_Disclosure) and associated [Relative Path Traversal](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Relative_Path_Traversal)

   1. i.e. what's to stop someone passing in the path to a sensitive file (e.g. your web.config file) and potentially obtaining information that could assist with attacking your system?
2. Maintainability

   1. Clients may maintain a copy of a URI for reuse or distribution - what happens if the file paths change? Some related conversation on this topic here: [Cool URIs don't change](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html)

My suggestion - you don't have to put the files themselves in a database, but put a list of files in a database, and use a unique identifier in the URL (e.g. perhaps a [slug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL#Slug) or [GUID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid(v=vs.110).aspx)).  Look up the identifier in the database to discover the path, then return that file.

This ensures:

1. Nobody can read a file that you haven't indexed and determined is safe to be downloaded
2. If you move the files you can update the database and client URIs will not change
3. And to respond to your original question, you can easily ensure the unique identifier is only made up of URI safe characters

Once you have the database, over time you may also fine it useful to maintain other metadata in the database such as who uploaded the file, when, who downloaded it, and when, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, Chris! Some very good/useful points you've presented there. One problem with your suggestion is keeping the database up to date... If new files are added to the source folder, moved or deleted, the database will have to be manually updated...

Comment: Depending on the nature and quantity of the API clients that might be a good thing - e.g. if you had 50 API clients and you moved a file, would you prefer to update 50 clients, or one database entry?  If you can update your question with more information about the client-server relationship (how many clients, how do they obtain knowledge of what path to put in the api URI, etc.) it would help with presenting a better answer.